# I want to make a router with raspberry pie and extend the wifi

Tags: wifi, wireless

[image]

I'm going to use Raspberry Pi to create the same environment as the image above

[image]

By the way, I'm trying to implement the router in the indicated part, but that part is using two wii modules, so one is connected to wifi and the other is in AP mode, is there a separate router setting?

By the way, I'm trying to implement the router of the part I marked, but it says that I use two wifi modules on the Internet, connect one wifi, and then use the AP mode on the other side, is this the right implementation?

---

https://itigic.com/ko/configure-raspberry-pi-or-linux-system-as-wifi-router/

Is the data in the link above correct the implementation router information I want?

Comment: it's not a `pie`

Comment: friend. If you want to make a router did u see the tutorials to make a router. Here is a link it may help you :) https://raspberrytips.com/openwrt-on-raspberry-pi/ Contact me if it works.

Comment: If this router needs to handle more than one or two clients, don't use a Pi, it will be very disappointing.  And even with a single client, the connection speed will be noticeably less than what you'd get from a $15 AP/extender.